# Appendix Incorrect Format

Tags: koma-script, chapters, appendices, thesis, scrbook

My latex file looks as follows: I have a `main.tex` that includes the packages and all ingredients of a thesis (here for minimum running example only one chapter and importantly the appendix).

```latex
% Create an appendix in LaTeX
\documentclass[bibtotoc,liststotoc,BCOR5mm,DIV12]{scrbook}
\title{Appendix Debug}

%packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}               % create hyperlinks
\usepackage[<options>]{scrlayer-scrpage}                    % header and footer line

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

% --------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter 
    \chapter{A normal chapter}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------
\backmatter 
    \input{./misc/annex}

\end{document}
```

Then, I have the exemplary `annex.tex` file given in a directory called `misc` given as:

```latex
\appendix
\addchap{Annex}

\begin{appendix}

\section{A section}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:sum}
    x_k = \frac{a_k+b_k}{2}
\end{equation}

\section{False Position}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{Another Appendix}
\lipsum[24]

\end{appendix}

\endinput
```

I'm not sure why this is, but to my knowledge appendices are of the form 'A.1, B.1, B.2.1' and not given as this 'raw' chapter as shown in the screenshot below

[image: Contents with incorrect Appendix ennumeration]

vs I would desire it to look like this (illustrative)

[image: desired outcome]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  What's happening, and what are you wanting to happen?  Also, for your MWE, skip the `\input` and `\endinput`, and just paste your appendix code at that spot.

Comment: `\appendix` converts chapters into appendices (for document classes which support chapters).  `\begin{appendices}` (note the spelling) is used by the appendix package to do the same thing plus add an appendix page (`\part*`).  To make appendix sections, use the subappendices environment.  Note that `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}` are implemented using `\foo` and `\endfoo`.

Comment: @Teepeemm I have added screenshots, so I hope the question is now clearer.

Comment: You main problem is that `\backmatter `is changing everything.  The easy solution is to not use it.  Otherwise you need to find out whether this is standard or another KOMA "implrovement" and how to undo all the things it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

As John already told in a comment, you are using `\backmatter` before the appendix heading. From the KOMA-Script manual, documentation of `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter` (currently section “3.15. Book Structure”:

> In the front matter, […]chapter headings in the header are
> not numbered. […] The chapters in the back matter are similar to the chapters in the front matter

So chapters in the back matter are not numbered, but it seems you want numbered chapters. You also don't need package `appendix` to have an appendix as shown in your illustrative image. You just need KOMA-Script's `\appendix`, which is a command not an environment. Therefore you should remove `\backmatter` and use, e.g.:

```latex
% Create an appendix in LaTeX
\documentclass{scrbook}
\title{Appendix Debug}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A normal chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\appendix

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Second}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\subsection{Yet another subsection}

\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

to get

[image: with number end dots]

If you also want to remove the dots after the numbers, you can use option `numbers=noenddot`:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\title{Appendix Debug}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A normal chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\appendix

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Second}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\subsection{Yet another subsection}

\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

[image: without number end dot]

Using package `appendix` would also be possible. In this case you should use environment `appendices` instead of command `\appendix`:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\title{Appendix Debug}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A normal chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Second}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\subsection{Yet another subsection}

\section{Another section}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: using package appendix]
Here the appendix chapters are prefixed by `Appendix` in the table of contents. This is because of option `titletoc` (copied from your example code). If you don't want this prefix, remove the option.

Note: I've also removed `\mainmatter`, because without `\frontmatter` IMHO it would not make sense.